# Octave script loop only runs once

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, octave

I have a script that reads images, overlays scatterplot points on them, and then combines all of the resulting images into a movie.  I have run into some difficulty translating the script to work in Octave though.  I have worked out all of the kinks, except that my loop only runs once.  I.e. The video created is only one frame long.  I suspect that this may have something to do with gcf?  ALthough I've been looking at it so long that I think it might just be something simple i'm missing.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

The loop is:

```
for i = 1:subsamp:numel(dd)
    if (mod(i,100)==0)
        fprintf('frame %d/%d\n', i, numel(dd));
    end

    % read current image and trim its width and height to a multiple of 4
    img = imread([img_dir,'/',dd(i).name]);
    trim_x = mod(size(img,2),4);
    trim_y = mod(size(img,1),4);
    img = img(1:end-trim_y,1:end-trim_x);

    % display current image
    set(0,'CurrentFigure',hnd);
    imshow(img);

    % if there is truth for this frame, show it
    which_block = map(i);
    if (which_block > 0)
        % grab data chunk for this frame
        block = truth(starts(which_block):ends(which_block),:);
        pts = block(:,7:8);
        ids = block(:,2);

        % overlay tracks and ids
       hold on;
        scatter(pts(:,1),pts(:,2),5);
        hold off;
    end

    % add this frame to movie file
  getframe(img);

    mov = addframe(mov,frame);

end
```

and the "getframe()" function at the end is one I found elsewhere online.  It looks like this:

```
function frame = getframe (h)

  print ("tmp.fig", "-djpg");
  frame = im2double (imread ("tmp.fig"));
  ## Truncate to even size to accomodate addframe()
  if (mod (size (frame, 1), 2) > 0); frame = frame(2:end, :, :); endif
  if (mod (size (frame, 2), 2) > 0); frame = frame(:, 2:end, :); endif

endfunction
```

Again, if you notice anything that could be stopping this from iterating through every frame it's much appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: What are the values of dd and subsamp?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `frame = getframe(img);` instead of `getframe(img);`? As far as I can see `frame` isn't defined when calling `mov = addframe(mov,frame);`.